# Intermittent FB.login() called before FB.init()

Tags: javascript, facebook

I a trying to implement Facebook connect in my project and it works 90% of the time. I am running the following code initiate FB SDK

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    console.log("initing")
    FB.init({
        appId    : app_id,
        status   : true,
        xfbml    : true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log("getting login status", response)
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            canEnter = 1;
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: siteurl+"/Introduction/ajax_facebook",
                data: {'facebook_user_id': uid},
                success: function(data)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

When it works my log `console.log("getting login status", response)` runs but every so often it doesn't get called and I get the error `FB.login() called before FB.init().` when I click login with Facebook button.

It would appear FB.init never finishes. Why would that be?

Comment: did you check the browser console and the network tab to see what´s happening? maybe it is just too slow? in general, i would use my own login button with FB.login (maybe you are doing this already) and only enable it when FB.init was called.

Comment: Nothing in console, hence my own logging. In the times where it doesn't work, FB.init doesn't get called so the login button would never get invoked

Comment: Please show your login button code as well. Btw., hope you are aware that anyone could send any ID to your server-side script, right?